# PyCharm's Problem with shared folder of VirtualBox

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, python, shared-folders, pycharm

I have installed Ubuntu in the VirtualBox on Windows 7 host then I shared a folder from windows host to Linux in the VirtualBox and add my login user to vboxsf group.

Now I can compile latex files using TexStudio, run .r files from Rstudio and run Python files using python interpreter in the terminal directly on the files in the shared folder. So far all is good.

PyCharm can open the file, However the problem is when I am trying to run a python file inside PyCharm IDE  it returns this error.

```
/usr/bin/python3.5: can't open file '/path/to/file.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

1. If it is problem with my user permission or python program's permission, Then how can I run them the same file from terminal.
2. If it is IDE's permission problem then why I can run R files using Rstudio and compile tex files in the same directory with TexStudio

Comment: What says "ls /path/to/file.py"? Is Where are the shared folders in the Ubuntu filesystem?

Comment: The path to file is exactly '/home/sp/Google_Drive/PhD/Subjects/Python/DataminingTutorials/regression.py'

Comment: The first path which I send was through a symbolic link which I have created to my home but the real path is.

/media/sf_Google_Drive/PhD/Subjects/Python/DataminingTutorials

but both of them return same error.

Comment: And what says "ls -l  /media/sf_Google_Drive/PhD/Subjects/Python/DataminingTutorials/regression.py"?

Comment: the result is :

-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 756 Jun 13 10:24 /media/sf_Google_Drive/PhD/Subjects/Python/DataminingTutorials/regression.py

Comment: The file seems to be lacking the required permissions. The last three dashes should be 'r-x' or 'rwx'. Otherwise if you aren't root or if your id is not in group vboxsf then you cannot access the file. To check if your id is in group 'vboxsf', issue "id" to list all groups it belongs to. You can also try to "cat" the file to  check the access.

Comment: I am sure I am in the group vboxsf this is why I can access the folder and run the file directly in the terminal as I explained in my question